# Google collect import in Drools

Tags: java, guava, drools

When I try to import MultiMap in Drools rule it caused an error below

```
[11,25]: [ERR 102] Line 11:25 mismatched input 'COLLECT' expecting 'identifier' in import
```

Does anyone know how can I import any com.google.common.collect in Drools rule?

P.S. Problem soleved
If anyone is interested you should use backquotes like below

```
com.google.common.`collect`.Multimap
```

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem soleved If anyone is interested you should use backquotes like below

`` com.google.common.`collect`.Multimap ``